# E QUERY [main] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:92

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've started learning mongodb. I am getting below error, not sure what went wrong.

```
E QUERY    [main] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:92
```

Here is my query:

```
> db.author.insert([{"x":null},{"y":true}, {"a":3.23}, {"b":"abc"}, {"c":new Dat
e()}, {"d":[{1,2,3}]}, {"e":{"f":1}}])
```

Please correct me what mistake in above query

Comment: can anyone please look into above?

Comment: Hint:  `{"d":[{1,2,3}]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{"d":[{1,2,3}]}` is an invalid document, as all documents must have a key before the value. If you want to add an array of numbers, you must change it to `{"d":[1,2,3]}` or provide a key for each element, like `{"d":[{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}]}`.